# How can some XML namespace tags be used without prefix?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I have seen examples of XML files like below

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>
<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>
</root>
```

Also I have seen the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <bean id="test" />

</beans>
```

I am confused as to why the first one needs the prefixes and the second one does not. Are the prefixes needed only in case of ambiguity? Is there something in the root tag declaration in 2nd which causes the prefix to be optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic.

In the first case, the `root` element is in the default namespace. The two `table` elements are in two different namespaces, so they have the `f` and `h` prefixes.

In the second case, the `beans` element is in the `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` namespace. It could have been specified with a prefix like

```
<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <b:bean id="test" />

</b:beans>
```

however, since there's only a single namespace, it's just simpler to specify `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` as the namespace for all of the elements.